# Natural Language Entity extraction

Tags: php, mysql, nlp

I have a text which requires entities to be tagged.

Example:

**David is specialised in bipolar disorder and works in institution University of California.**

I have table with all the entities in one table ,called **entities** and table contains 1 million records.

Of course i would write and scan each one of those to find the entities,but problem would be performance.

What is the best approach to identify entities like bipolar disorder and University of California from the table list.

```
 I expect the out put to be in format
 array("bipolar disorder","California");
```

Comment: Go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this. it seems you don't want to use optimised sql query. you can use indexes to improve performance of your query.